# Variables returning "undefined" or no data in email script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, undefined, google-forms

I am trying to make a script send an confirmation email from a sheet, triggered by "On form submit".
It all works apart from 2 variables which it seems the script doesn't pick up.
One of these variables comes from another function and is pasted into the sheet.
The other variable is a reference number which is created in the sheet each time new data is entered.

Code:

```
function myFunction(e) {

  var userName = e.values[2];  //this info comes from form and works
  var teamName = e.values[1];  //this info comes from form and works
  var recipient = e.values[4]; //this info comes from form and works
  var refNumber = e.values[22]; //this info comes from an array in a column and returns "undefined"
  var NetballWeekend = e.values[6]; //this info comes from form and works
  var editURL = e.values[20]; //this info comes from another function which pastes it into column "U" and returns blank

  var subject = "SunSports Netball Weekend - Your Booking for " + teamName + "." ;
  var body = "Hello " + userName + "."
 + "\n" + "We have received your booking form for the " + NetballWeekend + "."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `e.values` is an event object bound to the event `onFormSubmit`

- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) means that those values are tied to the event, or in other words, for formSubmit it's the values that have beens ubmitted through the form
- If you populate the row of freshly submitted values from the form response with additional values, those values cannot be retrieved with `e.values`
- Instead, you can use `e.range.getRow()` to retrieve the row number contianing the newest form submission and retrieve the manually added values with e.g.  `getRange(e.range.getRow(), 21).getValue()`
- Mind that if the values in column U and W are added posteriorly once the the form data has been submitted, they might not be avaialble directly on form submit but slightly delayed
- In this case they might be `undefined` onFormSubmit and the best approach would be to wait e.g. by incorporating [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) before retrieving those values

Sample:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var userName = e.values[2];  //this info comes from form and works
  var teamName = e.values[1];  //this info comes from form and works
  var recipient = e.values[4]; //this info comes from form and works
  var refNumber = sheet.getRange(row, 23).getValue();
  var NetballWeekend = e.values[6]; //this info comes from form and works
  var editURL = sheet.getRange(row, 21).getValue();

  var subject = "SunSports Netball Weekend - Your Booking for " + teamName + "." ;
  var body = "Hello " + userName + "."
 + "\n" + "We have received your booking form for the " + NetballWeekend + "."
  ...
}
```

Comment: FABULOUS ! Thank you so much  ziganotschka, that is perfect.
Best regards and stay safe