# Google Forms Script sends emails to respondents 6 months later

Tags: email, google-apps-script, time, google-forms, eventtrigger

I want a Google Form to send a mail to respondents, but not right after it. I want the mail to be send 6 months later.
It's a mail that sends a second customer satisfaction survey, evaluating if my enterprise's services really helped in the long term.

My main problem is : I can't take the mail directly, so it won't even send a mail right after we submitted the form.

I took the Google Script tutorials, so the code to send a map is only here to test the code.

```
function sendMap(event) {
  var map = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker("76 pth Ave, New York");
  var mail = e.values[1];
  MailApp.sendEmail(mail, 'Map', 'See below.', {attachments:[map]});
}
```

I have set the project's triggers correctly but everytime I submit the form, I get a fail notification :

> ReferenceError: e is not defined (ligne 35, fichier "Code")

For the trigger based on time, I saw this code, but I'm not even sure how to insert it in mine :

```
function myFunction() {
 // Creates a trigger that runs 5 minutes later
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(5 * 60 * 1000) // 5 minutes plus tard
  .create();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I took it from the minimal code here that seems to work for the person who did it :  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97848/can-google-forms-send-emails-automatically/97982#97982 . 

I tried to replace it by `var mail = event.values[1];` to be similar to this code's syntax but it didn't work either.

Comment: It should be `event` not `e`. Explain what didn't work afterwards: error messages and [mcve]

Comment: This is the error message with `event` : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (ligne 35, fichier "Code")`

Comment: Where is this script put? Could you explain the steps you made to reach the script editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ReferenceError: e is not defined (ligne 35, fichier "Code")

implies that you are trying to run the function manually, this is something you cannot do if your code contains an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384228/variables-returning-undefined-or-no-data-in-email-script/62389499#62389499) for more information.

You can give any name to the event parameter, but the name of the function parameter and inside the funciton has to be the same. So, if you define `sendMap(event)`  - then it should also be `var mail = event.values[1];` and not `var mail = e.values[1];`

### What you can do is the following:

- Have a function that you bind to the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onFormSubmit` trigger
- This function will be called automatically when new form data populates the spreadsheet to which your script is bound
- Create a trigger within this function - and retrieve the [unique Id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getuniqueid) of the trigger
- Call from within the first function a second function that will create a [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) trigger
  Use [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to save the event object corresponding to each trigger event
- When your funciton on trigger is called - retrive the script properties corresponding to the trigger event
- Carry out the desired funcitonality (e.g. send email)
- [Delete old triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger) given that the allowed amount of triggers is limited

Sample

```
function sendMap(event) {
  var mail = event.values[1];
  var triggerUid = event.triggerUid;
  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
//change to .after(6 * 30 * 24 *60 * 60 * 1000) for approx 6 month or calculate the exact date
  .after(5 * 60 * 1000) // 5 minutes plus tard
  .create();  
  var id = trigger.getUniqueId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(id, mail);
}

function myFunction(event) {
  var id = event.triggerUid;
  var mail = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(id);
   var map = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker("76 pth Ave, New York");
  MailApp.sendEmail(mail, 'Map', 'See below.', {attachments:[map]});
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(id);
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if(triggers[i].getUniqueId() == id){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I submitted a form and I get this summary of failures for Google App Script : `01/07/20 12:44 sendMap TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined formSubmit 01/07/20 12:44`

Comment: In the journal, it says `1 juil. 2020 à 13:01:31 Erreur TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at sendMap(Code:2:26)` (I submitted a new form cause I had a lot of commented lines above. Now there's only the code you wrote).

Comment: It means line 26, so `var map = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker("76 pth Ave, New York");`. I assume that `event.values[1]` does not contain a valid email address. You can verify it with the line `Logger.log(mail);` before sending the actual mail.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to verify with `Logger.log(mail);` . Do I put it before the line ? I did so and the error didn't change. I change the line for `var mail = "my_email@yahoo.fr";`. Written like this, I receive the mail. But when I put `var mail = event.values[1];` and fill the form copy/pasting my email (I never write it but copy/paste it from my keepass file so I don't make any mistake) it doesn't work anymore. I created the form's question for email by checking the google parameter "collecting emails". Maybe I should change it and put the question myself ?

Comment: In chich column of the spreadsheet is `mail`? Wiiht `Logger.log` before ` MailApp.sendEmail` you can see the logs after the code runs, e.g. when you go on `View->Executions`.

Comment: It's the column B. Now there is also the column C because I added the question twice, to try with `[1]` and `[2]`. The error is still the same : `1 juil. 2020 à 15:30:52 Erreur TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at sendMap(Code:2:26)`. When I added Logger.log before `var mail = event.values[1];`, there was another error line : `1 juil. 2020 à 15:25:13 Infos null`

Comment: Are you trying to run your script MANUALLY by pressing the "run" button? As explained in my answer you can not do this if your code expect an event object as a parameter. The script will run automatically on form submit (provided you bound an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger to `function sendMap`). You can trace the execution of the script through `View->Executions`.

Comment: Based on the error `Cannot read property '1' of undefined     at sendMap`, `e` is defined, but `e.values` is not defined. It simply means @Melofrench is using the script inside Form and not Spreadsheet. The event object provided to form and sheet are different. The former doesn't contain `values` object.

Comment: Is this the case @Melofrench? As mentioned in the answer, this solution is for a script bound to a spreadsheet. As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), available `Form submit` event objects for Google Sheets and Google Forms are different. Either bind your script to the destinaiton spreadsheet instead of the form, or use the allowed event objects for the form (`e.response.getItemResponses().[1].getResponse()`)

Comment: It is the case. I changed the line 2 with this : `function sendMap(event) {
  var mail = event.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse(); 
}` 

After multiples errors, I understood that `[1]` was getting the next answer. I'm surprised that this solution works only if I create an other question for the mail but not if I set the parameter to get emails. However, it doesn't matter if this parameter is on since it works like this. Thank both of you for your help.

Comment: `var mail = event.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();` should also work if the answer to the first question contains a valid `email`. In any case, I am glad it works for you now.